# "Inferred type is ambiguous" error using Data.Vector

Tags: haskell

The following code fails to compile, with the error message given below. `f` should simply be a state monad which when run creates a vector of length one with a single int "42". I suspect some ambiguity is happening between `run` and `unstream` much like `show . read`, but I can't figure out how to resolve it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Data.Vector.Generic.New (run, unstream)
import Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream (singleton)

f = run . unstream . singleton $ (42 :: Int)

main = return ()
```

Error:

```
main.hs:6:1:

Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector v0 Int)
  arising from the ambiguity check for `f'
from the context (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector v Int)
  bound by the inferred type for `f':
             Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector v Int =>
             GHC.ST.ST s (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable v s Int)
  at sort.hs:6:1-44
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector v0 Int)
When checking that `f'
  has the inferred type `forall (v :: * -> *) s.
                         Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector v Int =>
                         GHC.ST.ST s (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable v s Int)'
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous

main.hs:6:1:

Could not deduce (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable v0
                  ~ Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable v)
from the context (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector v Int)
  bound by the inferred type for `f':
             Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector v Int =>
             GHC.ST.ST s (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable v s Int)
  at sort.hs:6:1-44
NB: `Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable' is a type function, and may not be injective
Expected type: Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable v s Int
  Actual type: Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable v0 s Int
Expected type: GHC.ST.ST
                 s (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable v s Int)
  Actual type: GHC.ST.ST
                 s (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable v0 s Int)
When checking that `f'
  has the inferred type `forall (v1 :: * -> *) s1.
                         Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector v1 Int =>
                         GHC.ST.ST s1 (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Mutable v1 s1 Int)'
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `show . read` problem, but with a twist.

The two functions we are composing here are

```
unstream :: forall s v a. (Vector v) => Stream a -> New v a
run :: forall s v' a'. New v' a' -> ST s (Mutable v' s a')
```

Composing them yields `New v a ~ New v' a'`, and since `New` is a datatype, it is injective; thus we have `v ~ v'` and `a ~ a'`, for:

```
run . unstream :: forall s v a. (Vector v) => Stream a -> ST s (Mutable v s a)
```

However, the choice of `v` is unspecified by the type `Stream a -> ST s (Mutable v s a)`, since `Mutable` is a type family, and is thus not injective. This is where it becomes like `show . read :: forall a. (Show a, Read a) => String -> String`; it is just harder to see because `v` seems to occur in the type.

Think about what happens when you use it at a more concrete type, e.g.

```
run . unstream :: forall s. Stream Int -> ST s (MVector s a)
```

there is no possible way to know what `v` is supposed to be just from `Mutable v ~ MVector`.

All this suggests a way to type `run . unstream . singleton` polymorphically, without pre-committing to a choice of `v`, by just requiring it to be passed at call sites:

```
{- LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

f :: forall s v a. (Vector v a) => Proxy v -> a -> ST s (Mutable v s a)
f _ = run . (unstream :: Stream a -> New v a) . singleton
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generally resolve ambiguities like these by attaching a type annotation. In this case, the question is, "Which instance of `Vector v a` should I use when unstream creates a `New v a`?". This can be resolved either by putting an annotation on `run` or `unstream`, but it looks as though an annotation on `unstream` would be less (finger) typing. Something like this:

```
f = run . (unstream :: Stream Int -> New {- put something concrete here -} Int) . singleton $ 42
```